# Implementation 3D Secure Paypal Cardinal Commerce with C# sample code

Tags: security, paypal, integrate, 3d-secure

I am working in asp.net C# application with 4.0 framework. I need to integrate cardinal commerce payment API. Can you anybody give any sample code and or CMPCDotNet.dll file for that API integration using C#?

Comment: If there is an API, then I am sure there is an official site with some documentation. Have you checked that documentation?